# Printservicelookup.lookupprintservice is empty in java 1.8 on a linux server

Tags: java, linux, printing, cups

I am trying to print a job in Linux(RHEL7) server using cups(1.6.3).

I'm using:

```
PrintService[] lPrintServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, lAttributeSet);
```

`lPrintServices` has a size of `0`.

However I'm able to run the same code in Windows local machine and able to return the value of `lPrintServices`.

If I run through Linux it is empty. Am I missing something in the`Cups configuration or in the code?

Comment: Do you mean that `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices` is returning `null`? If that's the case you have an array of matching PrintService objects representing print services that support the specified flavor attributes. If no services match, the array is zero-length.

Comment: I just had a look at the source code of PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices and it's not possible for that method to return `null`. There must be something wrong in your code. Post an [mcve] of the real code that you are using.

Comment: Thanks James , Sorry, Its returning 0 length. But it has three printers connected to it. It should not return array zero-length. So i am wonderiung what the problem is.